# how to format date in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am retrieving a string in the form of "2010-10-20" from a xml database,and every time this string keeps on changing.I need to format this string to something like October 20 2010.I tried using SimpleDateFormat and then calling the format method on it and passing the string as the argument.But the execution stops when it encounters this line.Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Hey thank you,actually i have solved it with the issue by myself

Comment: in that case u should answer your own question so that it may help others :)

Comment: @Swati Surely,its all about working in a team,any help needed shud b given,hope u do the same wid others too

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma");
Date timenow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"));
cal.setTime(timenow);
String formatedTime = sdf.format(cal);

or 

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
DateFormat.getInstance(DateFormat.DATETIME_DEFAULT).formatLocal(sb,System.currentTimeMillis());
String localFormatedDate = sb.toString();
```